# I/O from user space to devices

Tags: linux, file-io, io, operating-system, kernel

If we want to write to a device, we first store our data in a character array, and transfer the array to the kernel. In a simple implementation, the kernel first copies data from the user space to the kernel space, and then proceeds to write the data to the device. Instead of having two copies of the same data, can we have a single copy of the data? This implementation could lead to a higher performance. Also, the same thing happens where we need to read a device. Here also, the kernel first reads the data from the device, and then transfers data to the user’s memory space (double buffering). How do we optimize this, and manage with only a single copy of data? Can we do both of these things, without compromising the security? How can it be done, for example, in Linux or Windows?

Comment: Do you mean a specific OS? If yes, then, please, specify it in the question post (and in the tags).

Comment: @Tsyvarev please explain for Linux or Windows, for whichever you might know anything.